# Per topic permissions?

Tags: google-groups, permissions

I am managing a very chaotic group where everyone would post anything (well not quite, but still) on any unrelated topic. My goal is to keep them informed about some updates concerning everyone. I'd like something like a dedicated thread where only I, the group admin, could post messages.

Is that doable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the option `Lock replies`:

[image]

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/transition-sfv/3Jdz8DMUaT0/5WIYUiE7P8UJ:

- **Lock Replies** - Disallow any replies to topic(s). Topics that have replies locked have a gray lock icon next to their names. The Post reply button will also disappear from within these topics.
  Unlock Replies.
- **Lock Topic** - Disallow any actions in the Actions menu to be performed on topic(s). Topics that have been locked have an orange lock icon next to their names. Most all menu items in the Actions menu will also disappear when locked topics are selected.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how that feature works, and how it solves the OP's problem?

Comment: Sure, answer edited.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Although this locks the specific topic, email replies can still be sent to it and the googlegroup will open another topic named "Re: [locked topic's name]". Anyway to prevent this too ?